# In SDN4 neo4jOperations.queryForObjects returns entities with empty collections. How to solve?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have entity, which looks like this:

```
@NodeEntity
class User {
    String name;
    boolean male;
    <...>
    @Relationship(type = "friend")
    Set<User> friends;
    @Relationship(type = "participation")
    Set<Event> events;
    <...>
}
```

In order to query male users I use the following code:

```
String q = "MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.male=true RETURN u";
Iterable<User> maleUsers = neo4jOperations.queryForObjects(User.class, q, emptyMap());
```

But it returns users with empty collections of friends and events.

Trying to fix the problem I got the following code:

```
String q = "MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.male=true WITH u MATCH p=(u)-[*0..1]-() RETURN p";
Iterable<User> maleUsers = neo4jOperations.queryForObjects(User.class, q, emptyMap());
```

And now collections are initialized. But this change brings a new problem:

- This code is intended to return: only male users
- But in fact it returns: male users and users, somehow related to male users

How to solve my problem properly? Any thoughts are very appreciated!

PS: I use Spring Data Neo4j 4.1.0.M1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you return a path which contains many User entities, and the OGM is unable to tell which one you want back. 
The best way to do this would be to use `session.query`:

```
Result result = session.query("MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.male=true WITH u MATCH p=(u)-[*0..1]-() RETURN u as user, nodes(p),rels(p)",emptyMap());
```

and then from `result`, retrieve each `user` which will have friends and events mapped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Seems like a good idea. But it doesn't work for me, since I have a node without any label (actually it is a Neo4j Spatial root node). Due to existance of it I encounter NPE in the RestModelMapper file. The line #153 contains the following expression: `metaData.resolve(nodeModel.getLabels()).getUnderlyingClass()`, where `nodeModel.getLabels()` returns an empty array for aforementioned node. This causes, that `metaData.resolve(nodeModel.getLabels())` returns null. And it fails... What can I do with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a bug- I've opened https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/150 for you to track it and it will be fixed asap. Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: Great thanks for the efforts! I will track the issue.

Comment: At the same time I prepared a temporary solution (workaround): https://github.com/victordombrovsky/Utils/blob/master/Neo4jUtils.java Currently I use it. Seems like it works fine. But maybe I'm wrong. Could you take a look at it in order to let me know if it has implicit problems? The main idea there - to populate the mapping context before performing a real query.